# What type of energy electrons store on different orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics, orbitals, ionization-energy

It's said that electrons, situated on different energy levels inside an atom, possess different amounts of some energy.

I'm interested in what is that energy.

Is it **kinetic** energy? Surely, electrons can't have definite position, nor speed, yet one can imagine that ground state orbital has somewhat "the slowest" electrons, whereas the top level orbital - somewhat "the fastest". Or how far is that from the truth?..

Also! I've got familiar with [ionization energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy) recently, where it's can clearly be seen (on a top graph) that this energy tend to decrease as atomic number goes up.

Therefore (quite silly now, but): does *that* mean that "the fastest" electrons are inside the lightest atoms?

What else energy types are good to mention?

Comment: It's customary to look at electrons in atoms *on their own* but it's fallacious to do so. It's the *system of electron(s) plus nucleus* that possesses energy. Specifically, Coulombic energy and kinetic energy.

Comment: @Gert okay, thanks! It's tempting to think then, that the difference in kinetic energy has something to do with "the volume" (and a shape) of an orbital.

Comment: It's tempting and also kind of correct. Look at a $\text{H}$ atom: the higher orbitals (take the $\text{s}$ orbitals as examples), $n>1$, make the atom 'puff up'. They also have higher energy.